# Who is supposed to be giving orders to the remaining Afghan diplomats of the pre-Taliban government?

Tags: international-relations, afghanistan

As outlined in [What's the point of continuing not to recognize the Taliban government of Afghanistan?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/78041/whats-the-point-of-continuing-not-to-recognize-the-taliban-government-of-afghan?noredirect=1), the Taliban government is not recognized by any nation in the world. However the *previous* government (led by [Ashraf Ghani](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ashraf_Ghani)) was not formally *unrecognized*, as far as I can tell. Therefore there are still credentialed diplomats in Afghanistan's diplomatic posts around the world. For example, [Naseer Faiq](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naseer_Faiq) serves as Afghanistan's "chargé d’affaires to the UN".

But... who is supposed to be giving orders to these diplomats? Ashraf Ghani never formed a "government in exile" and they're supposedly not allowed to take orders from the Taliban... so who is currently in charge of their mission, at least on paper?

Comment: follow the money perhaps?  who is paying them?  I assume it's from the frozen Afghanistan aid funds sitting around.

Comment: Googling "Afghan government in exile" gives some results (centred around Amrullah Saleh) but I'm struggling to say which are reliable sources, and most are from 2021.